# How does the algorithm for telling if a point is clockwise or counter-clockwise, relative to another point, actually work?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on implementing the Jarvis algorithm (a.k.a gift wrapping). For determining if a point p1 is clockwise or counter-clockwise relative to point p2, I am using this formula:  (y1-qY)*(x2-qX) - (x1-qX)*(y2-qY) = n     where q is the vertex of the angle formed by the two points. If n < 0, point1 is clockwise of point2. If n > 0, point1 is counter-clockwise of point2.

[image]

A) If p1 = (1.5, 34.5)[yellow dot], p2 = (1, 2.4)[red dot], and q = (2.5, 2)[orange dot], then 
n = (34.5 - 2)*(1 - 2.5) - (1.5 - 2.5)*(2.4 - 2) = -48.35

B) If p1 = (6, 2.4)[blue dot] and everything else remains unchanged, then
n6 = (2.4 - 2)*(1 - 2.5) - (6 - 2.5)*(2.4 - 2) = approximately -2.

Looking at a plot of the points, the blue dot is much more clockwise than the yellow dot (relative to red), but the formula is indicating that the yellow dot is the most clockwise point.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using this formula: (y1-qY)(x2-qX) - (x1-qX)(y2-qY) = n where q is the vertex of the angle formed by the two points. If n < 0, point1 is clockwise of point2. If n > 0, point1 is counter-clockwise of point2.

Correct, the sign of the cross product (=your formula) is the sign of the angle.

> the formula is indicating that the yellow dot is the most clockwise point

Why would you think that? No, the magnitude of the cross product does not (directly) correspond to the magnitude of the angle.

Fortunately, you don't need the magnitude of the angle to find the most clockwise point, because the most clockwise point is the point more clockwise than any other:

```
List<Point> jarvis(List<Point> points) {
    List<Point> hull = new ArrayList<>();
    Point q = Collections.min(points, Comparator.comparing(p -> p.x));
    do {
        hull.add(q);

        Point leftMost = null;
        for (Point p : points) {
            if (p == q) continue;
            if (leftMost == null || left(p,q,leftMost)) {
                leftMost = p;
            }
        }

        q = leftMost;
    } while (q != hull.get(0));
    return null;
}
```

Comment: this is "I'm not gonna answer your question but I have a new Ferrari for you"

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two questions: can you explain what the lambda is doing in the "Point q....." line? And: Where does the "left(p,q,leftMost)" come from?

Comment: @gpasch He did answer my question. The magnitude of the cross product  does not directly correspond to the magnitude of the angle, i.e. just b/c the blue dot is more clockwise, the formula I used will not necessarily result in the version with the blue point have a larger magnitude. That is why the yellow dot can have a greater n than the blue dot, even though blue is more clockwise

Comment: The lambda is specifying we start with the point having minimal x coordinate (we must start with a point on the convex hull or there may be no leftmost point). If you don't know lambdas yet you can use a linear search instead.

Comment: The `left` method is for you to implement, using your formula. `left(a, q, p)` return true if `a` is "left of" the ray from `q` to `p`.